# How to georeference an old picture through transformation values?

Tags: geocoding

I got a very old picture of a landscape which I have to georeference the right way. For that, I usually go in my QGIS version 2.12.3-Lyon to “Rasta” and then “Georeferencing”. Normally it’s easy, because I get the coordinates from google maps and then try to find the same points in my picture. Since it is a very old picture, it’s pretty hard to find the right points for the coordinates. I also got some transformation values, but I don’t know how to use them in QGIS and if it is even possible. Someone knows how those values could help me?
I added a few of those transformation values as example.
[image]

Edit: 
I georeferenced as suggested and added points with some random number and then later on I edited them to the right value. Now I have the problem that my picture is not at all where the points are (if you look very closely you can see a small spot on the left /down). And that the dx and dy values don’t fit with the values I got as transformation value. When I start the transformation I also don’t get the picture in the right place and it is like I didn’t georeferenced it at all… Someone knows how to proceed?
[image]

Comment: From where did you get the above transformations?  
QGIS Georeferencer can load GCP (ground control points) , as shown :    
*mapX,mapY,pixelX,pixelY,enable
24989.7451958386664046,26899.74328603783578728,1015.08131241084061003,-1262.71611982881631775,1
38260.0515760068083182,45133.75205268108402379,1623.92979641378451561,-423.01009037037590588,1
40324.04006834212486865,43339.89702355529152555,1712.82955191500673209,-507.21791433125616777,1*

Comment: I got them from the same person who gave me the picture... I just don't know how to use them and georeference the picture correctly...

Comment: Did you manage to open the raster image in Georeferencer plugin in QGIS  ?

Comment: No I actually didn't know that there is a plugin to georeference... What is the exact name of it?

Comment: In QGIS, From Plugins Menu , click on **Manage & install Plugins**. then search for **Georeferencer GDAL** and install it.

Comment: ahh yes, this tool I usually use to georeference a picture. But how do I use it when I just have the transformation values and don't know exactly where the point should be in the picture? Is it somehow possible to just introduce the values?

Comment: Yes, you can. try to add any random point using CTRL+A, then select random destination point as well from QGIS window, then you will find the **GCP table** in georeferencer plugin window and there you can edit the GCP as you want.

Comment: I tried as you said, but it doesn't show anything... and I also couldn't introduce the dx and dy values... some suggestions?

Comment: Check below image, you can edit values located the red rectangle (GCP table).  http://postimg.org/image/yxzdv7qtn/

Comment: I could edit all values but dx, dy and residual. There it is impossible to change the numbers.... And I also can't see the picture anymore, the points are at some other place... sorry but I am stucked...

Comment: dx,dy and residual change automatically when you define the coordinates of source & destination. Check the coordinates system of the project in QGIS as it may be the issue for the disappear of images.
reference for exact steps for georeferencing (http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html?highlight=georeferencer)

Comment: ahhh I am so lost... I did everything as you said, but I still have the points at a totaly diferent place then my picture... and when I load it in my project, its still at a completely different place... Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Verify which coordinates system used for the transformations you have and assign it to your QGIS project as the Georeferencer use the same Coord Sys of the project.

Comment: they are both in the same coordinates system (Gauss Krüger EPSG 31467)...